# Is it possible to track the 'isDeleted' field for custom objects?

Tags: history-tracking, field-history, system-fields

is there any way to track when record of a custom object was deleted or restored from recycle bin? I tried to export and find records from "History: Custom object" but this seems like the 'isDeleted field is not trackable.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a 'before delete' and 'after undelete' trigger to write to a custom object, storing the record id, timestamp and whether it was a delete or undelete.